# " 'app' is undefined " when developing an Office add-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ms-office, office-addins

So I am learning how to develop an MS Project add-in. 
I was successful in deploying the tutorial (yayy!): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/project-quickstart

Then I replaced the html and the js code with the example code from here: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/projectdocument.gettaskbyindexasync

And it stopped working!

I started a new project from scratch. Again, as in the tutorial, "Office Add-in project using Jquery framework", "Javascript" as selected options.
And it still didn't work.

Error message from F12 dev tools:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: 'app' is undefined ReferenceError: 'app' is undefined
>     at Anonymous function (eval code:14:13)
>     at mightThrow (https://localhost:3000/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3534:10)
>     at Anonymous function (https://localhost:3000/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3602:12) undefined
>
> SCRIPT5009: 'app' is undefined
>   jquery.js (3827,3)

The error is spawned from the following row from the JS code:

```
app.initialize();
```

There is no "app.initialize();" in the tutorial. If I decide to delete this row, the error goes away (naturally), but then interacting with the functionality spawns another error message:

> Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference

Then I tried to define some 'app' Object. 
I initialized it with

```
var app = Object.context;
```

The error then is:

> Unable to get property 'initialize' of undefined or null reference

I am still trying to figure out, where this 'app' Object comes from. Or at least, how can I define it properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the code you have at the moment?

Comment: Hi, here it is: https://github.com/pressijan/Project-Tutorial